# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject converts null to empty object

Tags: c#, json.net

Seems like a bug to me.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{\"arr\": [{\"prop1\": null}]}");
var prop1 = ob.arr[0].prop1; // has {} value
var test = ob.arr[0].prop1?.prop2; //causes error
```

`'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'prop2'`

Comment: Where should JsonConvert could get information about prop2? You are using dynamic, there is no structure definition with prop2.

Comment: if json is like thios `{\"obj\": {\"prop1\": null}}`  everything is fine

Comment: Related or duplicate: [string behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51776584/3744182) and [Newtonsoft Json.Net serialize JObject doesn't ignore nulls, even with the right settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259032/3744182) and [Null-coalescing operator returning null for properties of dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053805/3744182).

Answer (score 2):

`ob.arr[0].prop1` is not null (it is a non-null empty `JValue`), so the null coalescing operator doesn't halt the access chain.

Instead `ob.arr[0].prop1.Value` is null, so you may use:

```
var test = obj.arr[0].prop1.Value?.prop2;
```

or

```
var test = obj.arr[0].prop1.HasValues
  ? obj.arr[0].prop1.prop2 // this will be null in your case
  : null;
```

Comment: so what is the difference between `"{'arr': [{'prop1': null}]}"` and `"{'obj': {'prop1': null}}"`? Why `prop1` is `{}` in the first case and `null` in the second?

Comment: @Toolkit, I get `{}` in both cases.
For `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{'arr': [{'prop1': null}]}");`, `obj.arr[0].prop1` is `{}`.
For `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{'obj': {'prop1': null}}");`, `obj.obj.prop1` is `{}`

Comment: no it's wrong, if no array is present, null coalescing operator works fine, sorry wrong answer, not sure why people upvote